# Return records that were updated in the last 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-update

I have a procedure that updates two fields in my table `lt_transactions`, the `last_update_dt` and a calculated field called `rec_amt`  We also have a `create_dt` field that could either be the same value as the `last_update_dt` or less then it.

We need to add a small piece of code to our process to use `xp_sendmail` however the majority of the code uses a slew of temp tables.

The only thing I can think of is to query the `t_transactions` to find what records were updated within the last few minutes (we picked 5 just to be safe) and return those rows to start. The rows would have an  `last_update_dt` that has been changed anywhere from a second ago to about 5 minutes ago.

```
    select distinct cust_no,  rec_amt
    from t_transactions 
    where create_Dt <= last_update_dt  
    and  last_update_dt < dateadd(minute,-5,getdate())
    and rec_amt is not null
```

This is what I wrote, give me the customer value, the received (this is what has changed). where the created date is less then or equal to the last update date, where received amount isn't null and where the last update date is less then getdate minus 5 minutes.

I am clearly doing something wrong because I should get maybe 20 records a hundred tops, but I'm getting thousands and these records are from years ago and not ones that were updated a few minutes ago.

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the issue, i.e. show us a small number of rows and your query which isn't returning the correct rows.

Comment: And maybe consider changing from `<` to `>` since `last_update_dt < dateadd(minute,-5,getdate())` is going to show you all rows **older** than 5 minutes.

Comment: Seems like there must be a better solution anyway such as adding a flag `IsEmailed` to one of your temp tables and then using that to process them. Using a date range will either mean you miss some or double up.

Comment: @DaleK we can't add anything to these tables, and i was told I can't use the temp tables to reference rows for xp_sendmail since its doesn't see the temp tables anyways. that is why I'm looking for a way in the procedure to send minimal data to users - tracking the process without accessing temp tables and only looking at the actual table that was updated. If i can look at temp tables that would make it much simpler code. and I'll adjust the > sign

Comment: Curious - why are you using an outdated procedure to send email?  Especially since that requires a MAPI client installed on the server?  You should be using sp_send_dbmail instead.

Comment: If you cannot track the last time this process ran - then any time it fails to run you will be missing data.  And worse, depending on when that calculation is done - you could end up having gaps.  Ideally, you would have a table that tracks the last time this ran - so you can then pull everything from that time forward (updating the value in the table at the same time).